# how come my checkboxes don't become visisble ?

Tags: javascript, html, hidden

Hello I'm new to javascript & html and I have a question. I have some checkboxes that i would like to make visible using css but it doens't work. How come?

this is my html code where the checkboxes are hidden:

```
    <script src="../js/shop.js"></script>

    <div id="img">
    <button onclick="ShowCheckBoxes()"><img src="../images/winkelwagen.jpg"></button>
    </div>
    <a name="Pasgeborenen"><h3>Pasgeborenen</h3></a>
    <div class="section">
        <a name="Pika"> Pika blanket</a>
        <a><img src="../images/NB1.jpg" /></a>
        <p>€19.99 <input type="checkbox" name="Pika blanket" id="id1" style="visibility: hidden"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <a>Familie top</a>
        <a><img src="../images/NB2.jpg" /></a>
        <p>€19.99 <input type="checkbox" name="Pika blanket" id="id2" style="display:none;"></p>
    </div>
```

this is de js code that should make them visible but it doens't:

```
ShowCheckBoxes()
{
for(var i=1;i<=35;i++) {
    document.getElementById("id"+i).style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To make it visible:

```
document.getElementById("id"+i).style.display= "";
```

To hide it:

```
document.getElementById("id"+i).style.display= "none";
```

Comment: so you can't make it hidden in the html beforehand ? Cause I replaced style.visibility = "visible"; with .style.display= ""; but it didn't work.

Comment: @ThomasPen Yes you can as you have it in your example with style="display:none;"

Comment: Thanks now I don't have to change it all.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to add function. here this should do it. just replace jscript with this code and it will work. i have tried it.

```
function ShowCheckBoxes()
{
alert("test");
for(var i=1;i<=35;i++) {
    document.getElementById("id"+i).style.visibility = "visible";
}
}
```